# Multiple fused spurs

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a double socket, and I'd somehow like to power two extra fused switches. I think the double socket is connected to the ring main, and I believe there's an existing fused spur switch coming off it (there's three sets of wires going into the double socket). I will double check this - presumably turning off the socket via the consumer unit and checking for continuity across neutral, and also disconnecting the wire I think is a spur and then powering on and checking the switch is indeed dead.

I'd like to power two extra fused switches, ideally from the connections available via this socket. The stuff in dotted lines in the picture below. What are my options?

[image: desired wiring]

I believe I'm not allowed to take multiple spurs from a socket connected to a ring main. I think I'm allowed to take as many sockets as I like from a fused spur. So in my pic, is the fused spur switch from the fused spur switch OK, because the original spur from the double socket is already fused?

How about the switch on the left? How can I wire that? I don't think I can take that from the double socket as it already has a fused spur. Is something like a 'daisy chain' of the fused switches legal, and my best option? Something like this:

[image: Daisy chain fused spurs]

Or what if I replaced my double socket with something like this:

[image: fused plug socket]

Presumably that wouldn't help, and I'd still be limited to a single spur from it?

Or should I somehow extend the ring main via a junction box? Not ideal, as I'd struggle to leave a 'neat' job.

I also don't really understand the limitations. I guess the multiple spurs are to ensure that the wiring to the socket isn't overloaded, but equally I could plug in a multi outlet extension lead and connect as many fused plugs as I like to it.

Also, once I work out how it should be wired, what testing should I perform?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not qualified to argue this as a 'legal' building regs answer, but there's no 'rule', just a 'guideline' [the confusion is that fused spurs are not limited to one per socket, but unfused spurs are]. If you're going to play safe use 4mm cable on spurs not 2mm, then you don't need to worry about the 20A 'guideline'.